# AngularJS animation with increment "left"

Tags: angularjs, jquery-animate

I want to implement the following feature: when click a button, another div under the same controller move to right a little bit (left+=50). However, when I searched for ngAnimate and find that it is mostly about "start" and "end" state in CSS, not increment manipulation. (I am new to Angular).

I now have to use jquery animate to move.

1. I get `$($element)` from the controller
2. find the div I want to move, say `var toMove = $($element).find(".tomove")`
3. `toMove.animate({left:"+=50}, 200);`

I want to know if there is an elegant way in Angular to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't really provide a lot in the way of DOM manipulation, if you can't achieve the desired effect using CSS3 animations then using jQuery is probably your best bet.  Any time your doing DOM manipulation it should be encapsulated in a directive but aside from that there's nothing special in Angular for working with the DOM it's just whatever the browser/jQuery provides.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have access to a 'done' callback, and only need to support supporting browsers, then just CSS3 transitions should work. So

```
.my-el {transition: left 0.5s ...
```

And then in the directive set the `left` value dynamically on click. CSS will animate to the value from the current one.

If you want Angular to calculate when the transition finishes, and give you the ability to use a 'done' callback, then the only way I have found is to add a dynamically generated style sheet to the page, that contains a unique class with the target `left` value, and use $animate.addClass to add it. It feels like a bit of a long-winded faff though, so I can't quite recommend it, and would love a nicer way!